# Add and substract a day to a date stored in string variable TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dateadd

Using string parameter for start date and end date. Passing this values to a sql task editor in SSIS. Wanted to convert the start date to day - 1 and end date to + 1 day and then process the variable. My actual code is as below:

```
DECLARE @P_StartDate VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @P_EndDate VARCHAR(100)


SET @P_StartDate = ?
SET @P_EndDate = ?

IF (@P_StartDate!='' AND @P_EndDate!='')
    BEGIN
          SELECT @P_StartDate , @P_EndDate 
    END
```

Wanted to do the changes like below but this is not working. Please help.

```
DECLARE @P_StartDate VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @P_EndDate VARCHAR(100)


SET @P_StartDate = ?
SET @P_EndDate = ?

@P_StartDate = DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, max(@P_StartDate), 102)
@P_EndDate = DATEADD(day, 1, convert(date, max(@P_EndDate), 102)

IF (@P_StartDate!='' AND @P_EndDate!='')
    BEGIN
          SELECT @P_StartDate , @P_EndDate 
    END
```

Edit: I cannot use the variable as date type because i am using this string type variable to dynamically generate one big sql query inside another ssis variable. Can anyone please guide me if it is possible to achieve the same thing without using datetype variable.

Comment: Dates aren't strings, they're binary types. Don't store them as strings

Comment: There are 6 [date and time data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Server, and 5 of the have the ability to store a date value; all of them are **infinitely better** than a `varchar`. Choose the right data type and adding, or subtracting, a day to the value is child's play.

Comment: `Passing this values to a sql task editor in SSIS.` SSIS supports strongly typed parameters, as project parameters, variables, OLEDB Command task parameters etc. You can use `DT_DATE` or `DT_DBDATE` as the type among others. SSIS supports all SQL Server date types. There's no reason to use strings

Comment: *"I cannot use the variable as date type because i am using this string type variable to dynamically generate one big sql query inside another ssis variable"* That implies you are injecting parameters into the query, not parametrising them. If you parametrised you could most certainly use a strongly typed date and time value. I smell a [XY problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Please show how you *"dynamically generate one big sql query"*, I suspect it could be improved quite a bit

Answer (score 0):

Your script is ok, there is syntax error,

```
DECLARE @P_StartDate VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @P_EndDate VARCHAR(100)


SET @P_StartDate = '2021-10-20'
SET @P_EndDate = '2021-10-30'


set @P_StartDate = DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, @P_StartDate, 102))
set @P_EndDate = DATEADD(day, 1, convert(date, @P_EndDate, 102))

IF (@P_StartDate!='' AND @P_EndDate!='')
    BEGIN
          SELECT @P_StartDate , @P_EndDate 
    END
```

notice extra ")" here `DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, @P_StartDate, 102))`

Why use `max` ?

Really this is not clear,what you are trying to do.

> Edit: I cannot use the variable as date type because i am using this
> string type variable to dynamically generate one big sql query inside
> another ssis variable